# OnLoad method DataList item`s control

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

I am building a website right now using DataLists and I want to ask a question:

When using `OnLoad` on specific control in DataList item, the DataList has 5 items, but the function is called only 4 times (does what it needs to do but not on the last item)

C# code:

```
protected void ibDeleteAlbum_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataListItem item in DataList1.Items)
    {
        ImageButton btnDelAlbum = item.FindControl("ibDeleteAlbum") as ImageButton;
        btnDelAlbum.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

HTML code:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="4" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblAlbumID" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ibDeleteAlbum" type="image" runat="server" style="position:absolute; margin-right: 1.4vw; margin-top: 2.4vh;" Visible="false" ImageUrl="~/Images/ic_delete.png" OnClick="ibDeleteAlbum_Click" ToolTip="מחיקה" OnLoad="ibDeleteAlbum_Load" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ibShowAlbums" 
            runat="server" 
            class="album"
            ImageUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "coverPhoto") %>'
            CommandName="album" 
            CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID") %>' 
            OnCommand="ibShowAlbums_Command" />
        <div class="albumNameShow" runat="server"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "albumName") %></div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Thanks ahead!

Comment: Please post a single question per **question**. Anyway even a single question is far too broad in your case, usually the answer to "can I" is "try it out and see what happens". Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @HimBromBeere I know how to ask, I have edited the post look now

Comment: Please provide your code in form of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @HimBromBeere is it ok now? Can you help me please?

Comment: Did you debug that? I Set a breakpoint inti `ibDeleteAlbum_Load` and check (e.g. by using a watch) how many elements you have in `DataList1.Items`. From your code syou´ve provided it´s impossible to guess why your loop should break at one iteration.

Comment: What I did is a message to the output window whenever this method is called with the DataList1.Items.Count.
The output was: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
And as told, I have 5 items

Comment: Then count! To me your list contains numbers from zero (!!) to 4, which are **five** elements, not four. So how do you determine it´s only executed four times?

Comment: @HimBromBeere First time is 0...
Also, I can see at the website that just 4 elements of the 5 has the button that I am turning into visible

Comment: Sure, and is zero bad? What did you expect instead? One? Arrays and lists are zero-based, that means the very first item has the index zero. But I can´t see where you *use* that numbers, or in particular their *indexes*.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Nevermind, I did that each time the function called, it turnes the *sender* to visible (without foreach loop)